# Kafka on Ubuntu 20.04 can't connect to Zookeeper, throwing a 'Timed out waiting for connection' error. Works fine on Ubuntu 18.04. Any insights?

Tags: apache-kafka, ansible, apache-zookeeper, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04

I have successfully set up Kafka with Zookeeper on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but when attempting the same configuration on Ubuntu 20.04.6, Kafka is unable to connect to Zookeeper. The error message I am encountering is `Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING.` It's perplexing as the same setup works seamlessly on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

This is my Kafka server.log exception

this is kfka.yml.

```
---

- name: Setup Kafka Group
  group: name=kafka system=yes

- name: Setup Kafka User
  user: name=kafka system=yes group=kafka

- name: Download Kafka
  get_url: url = https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.4.1/kafka_2.13-2.4.1.tgz dest=/opt/kafka_2.13-2.4.1.tgz owner=kafka group=kafka

- name: Untar kafka
  unarchive:
    src=/opt/kafka_2.13-2.4.1.tgz
    dest=/opt
    creates= /opt/kafka_2.13-2.4.1
    copy=no
    owner=kafka
    group=kafka

- name: Create Symlink
  file:
    src= /opt/kafka_2.13-2.4.1
    path=/opt/kafka
    state=link

- name: Create systemd configuration
  template: dest =/etc/systemd/system/kafka.service owner=root group=root mode=644 src=files/kafka.service.j2

- command: systemctl daemon-reload

- name: Create Kafka Data directory
  file: path=/app/kafka/data owner=kafka group=kafka mode=u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX recurse=yes

- name: Remove lost+found in the Data directory
  file: path="/app/kafka/data/lost+found" state=absent

- name: Create Log directory
  file: path=/var/log/kafka state=directory owner=kafka group=kafka mode=755

- name: Link configuration directory to /opt/kafka/config
  file: path=/etc/kafka state=link src=/opt/kafka/config

- name: Create log4j.properties
  template: dest={/etc/kafka/log4j.properties owner=kafka group=kafka mode=644 src=files/log4j.properties.j2

- name: Copy logrotate configuration
  template: dest=/etc/logrotate.d/kafka owner=root group=root mode=644 src=files/logrotate.conf.j2

- name: Create server.properties
  template: dest=/etc/kafka/server.properties owner=kafka group=kafka mode=644 src=files/server.properties.j2

- name: Enable Kafka daemon service
  shell: systemctl enable kafka

- name: Start kafka daemon service
  service: name=kafka state=restarted

- set_fact: kafka_ports="[]"

- name: Verify PLAINTEXT listener
  set_fact: kafka_ports="['9092']"
  when: verify

- name: Verify Kafka port
  debug: msg="ports to verify {{kafka_ports}} Kafak listen address {{kafka_listen_address | default('localhost')}} - {{ansible_hostname}}}}"

- name: Wait for Kafka to start
  wait_for: host={{kafka_listen_address | default('localhost')}} port=9092 state=started timeout=30
  with_items:
    - "{{kafka_ports}}"
  when: verify

- name: List topics
  command: /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
#  sudo_user: kafka
  register: kafka_topics

- name: Create Kafka topics
  shell: /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor {{replication_factor}} --partitions {{partition}} --topic {{item.topic}}
  with_items: 
    "{{topics}}"
  when: item.topic not in kafka_topics.stdout_lines
```

kafka error log

```
[2023-12-10 04:48:06,889] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-12-10 04:48:06,890] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2121 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-12-10 04:48:06,906] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to localhost:2121. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-12-10 04:48:06,937] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-12-10 04:48:12,941] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-12-10 04:48:13,057] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-12-10 04:48:13,064] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:259)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:255)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:113)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1858)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:375)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:399)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:207)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:84)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

this is zookeeper.yml

```
---

- name: Setup Zookeeper Group
  group: name=zookeeper system=yes

- name: Setup Zookeeper User
  user: name=zookeeper system=yes group=zookeeper

- name: Update apt cache and install Zookeeper
  apt:
    name: zookeeperd
    update_cache: yes

- name: Setup zoo.cfg file
  template: src=files/zoo.cfg.j2 dest=/etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg

- name: Setup myid file
  template: src=files/myid.j2 dest=/etc/zookeeper/conf/myid

- name: Setup Java Environment
  template: src=files/java.env.j2 dest=/etc/zookeeper/conf/java.env

- name: Create Log directory
  file: path=/var/log/zookeeper state=directory owner=zookeeper group=zookeeper mode=755

- name: Create Data directory
  file: path=/var/lib/zookeeper state=directory owner=zookeeper group=zookeeper mode=755

- name: Create log4j properties
  copy: src=files/log4j.properties dest=/etc/zookeeper/conf/log4j.properties owner=zookeeper group=zookeeper mode=644

- name: Create logrotate configuration
  template: src=files/logrotate.conf.j2 dest=/etc/logrotate.d/zookeeper owner=zookeeper group=root mode=644

- name: Restart Zookeeper Service
  service: 
    name: zookeeper.service 
    state: restarted
```

This is zookeeper log

```
2023-12-08 19:31:59,213 - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@136] - Reading configuration from: /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
2023-12-08 19:31:59,217 - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
2023-12-08 19:31:59,219 - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
2023-12-08 19:31:59,220 - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
2023-12-08 19:31:59,221 - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@116] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
2023-12-08 19:31:59,232 - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@136] - Reading configuration from: /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
2023-12-08 19:31:59,233 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@98] - Starting server
2023-12-08 19:31:59,245 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13-5build1--1, built on Tue, 18 Feb 2020 10:26:56 +0100
2023-12-08 19:31:59,251 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:host.name=kafka-node
2023-12-08 19:31:59,252 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.version=1.8.0_392
2023-12-08 19:31:59,252 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.vendor=Private Build
2023-12-08 19:31:59,252 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
2023-12-08 19:31:59,252 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.class.path=/etc/zookeeper/conf:/usr/share/java/jline.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlParserAPIs.jar:/usr/share/java/netty.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-api.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-log4j12.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper.jar
2023-12-08 19:31:59,252 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
2023-12-08 19:31:59,252 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2023-12-08 19:31:59,252 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2023-12-08 19:31:59,254 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.name=Linux
2023-12-08 19:31:59,255 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.arch=amd64
2023-12-08 19:31:59,255 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.version=5.4.0-167-generic
2023-12-08 19:31:59,255 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.name=zookeeper
2023-12-08 19:31:59,255 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.home=/home/zookeeper
2023-12-08 19:31:59,255 - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.dir=/
2023-12-08 19:31:59,262 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@836] - tickTime set to 2000
2023-12-08 19:31:59,262 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@845] - minSessionTimeout set to -1
2023-12-08 19:31:59,263 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@854] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1
2023-12-08 19:31:59,270 - INFO  [main:ServerCnxnFactory@117] - Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory
2023-12-08 19:31:59,274 - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@89] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
```

Comment: Why use an old version of Kafka? It doesn't need Zookeeper anymore. And why an version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The port is wrong in zookeeper.connect property

From Zookeeper logs

```
binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
```

From Kafka logs

```
INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to localhost:2121
```

If you want to use Ansible to setup Kafka, I'd suggest using Confluent's playbooks, and a recent version of Ubuntu